# venn diagram with categorical data

Tags: r, venn-diagram, gplots

I have three categorical vectors that represent symptoms. And I would like plot a venn diagram that show how many people have one two or three of them.
I tryed do

library(gplots)

venn(list(sym1, sym2, sym3))

but didn't work

Thank you

```
sym1=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)

sym2=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)

sym3=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: It works for me, though the example data are all identical so you just get 257 in the three-way intersection. Can you be more specific about what didn't work?

Comment: You need to load `gplots` not `gplot`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to achieve this with the library eulerr which provides much better looking (at least in my opinion) diagrams:

```
library(eulerr)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123) #for reproducible plot
data.frame(sym1, sym2, sym3)%>% #combine the vectors to a data frame
  mutate_at(1:3, as.logical) %>% #convert to logical
  euler(shape = "ellipse", input = "disjoint") %>% #calculate euler object, plot as ellipse
  plot(quantities = T) plot it
```

[image]

with `venn` from `gplots`:

```
library(gplots)
data.frame(sym1, sym2, sym3)%>%
  mutate_at(1:3, as.logical) %>%
  venn()
```

[image]

From the help of `venn`:

> Either a list list containing vectors of names or indices of group
>   intersections, or a data frame containing boolean indicators of group
>   intersectionship (see below)

In your case I trust the second options is desired.

Comment: The [Vennerable](https://github.com/js229/Vennerable) package is also worth a shout out imo

Comment: @Mariane Campos You welcome. If the answer solved your problem consider marking as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you @missuse. The second plot is exactly what I need. My R doesn't reconize the function  `mutate_at`.

Comment: @Mariane Campos did you load both the libraries? `library(tidyverse)` as well as `library(gplots)`? If you do not have `tidyverse` I recommend installing it, since it provides a plethora of useful functions, When you learn to use them R will be a pleasure to use.